# Google Maps API without using GWT

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm new to JavaScript, I need to display google maps v2 or v3(V3 is better) in my application without using gwt. Please Help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends according to your need. If you need to plot lot of regions, you can use kml in google map. you can create a kml file from shape file itself..

Answer (score 0):

You could embed a map this way:

- http://maps.google.com.sg/help/maps/getmaps/plot-one.html

Or if you want to do it programatically, read the documentation:

- https://developers.google.com/maps/
- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial

Comment: I want to use google maps for web application. I'm developing that using java and javascript. Is that possible to implement google maps through js. Hope this may be very simple, but i'm new to js...